# Nginx conf for laravel not work

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm using laravel in my centos 6.7 and webuzo.
I can run my script on apache before, but when i mirgate it to nginx, it won't run.
I think the problem is, i can't use this nginx conf :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name myapp.localhost.com;
root /srv/smile/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log error;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Everytime i put this config in nginx.conf, nginx service won't restart. What could be wrong with this conf ?

Comment: If this is exactly what you have as your site conf, you're missing a closing `}` for your `server` block.

Comment: Sorry, it missed when i paste here. I used closing } on my conf.

Comment: What do you get when you run: `sudo nginx -t`?

Comment: i got this error :

nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/nginx.conf:44
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: I think `nginx` is telling you that you are missing the outer `http { }` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure) for details.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/akshaykhale1992/nginx-php-mysql-setup

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks superman ! I spend 2 weeks and got nothing. You solved my problem :D